# On netlogo, what command do I use to make a turtle stop if the patch it wants to move to is a certain color

Tags: netlogo

I'm making a maze on netlogo and I want to do it so that once it tries to walk into the violet lines, it'll stay on its own patch instead of moving forward.  What command would that be? I tried bk 1 to reverse the fd 1 but it doesn't work all the time

Comment: `ask turtles
      [
      ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != ForbbidenColor
      [
         Your-Move-Function
         ]
      [
        Your-Bounce-Function 
        ]
      ]`

Answer (score 2):

You can undo your step like this:

```
ask turtles [
  fd 1
  if pcolor = violet [fd -1]
]
```

Or you can check ahead of time as Marzy answered. Basically it's the difference of asking for forgiveness vs permission :-)

Comment: difference of asking for forgiveness vs permission  :) Nice metaphor!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example answer your questions:

```
turtles-own [target]
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask n-of 100 patches [
    set pcolor red
    ]
  create-turtles 1 
  [ move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != red]
    set heading 90 
    set target one-of patches with [pcolor != red] 
    ask target 
    [
      set pcolor green
      ]
    ]
end

to go

  ask turtles
  [ifelse pcolor != green 
  [
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != red
    [
      Your-Move-Function
    ]
    [
      Your-Bounce-Function 
    ]
    leave-a-trail

  ]
  [stop
  print ticks
  ]
  ]
  tick
end


to Your-Move-Function
  let t target 
  face min-one-of all-possible-moves [distance t]
  fd 1
end

to Your-Bounce-Function 
  let t target 
  face min-one-of all-possible-moves [distance t]
  end

to-report all-possible-moves
  report patches in-radius 1 with [pcolor != red and distance myself  <= 1 and distance myself  > 0 and plabel = "" ]
end

to leave-a-trail
  ask patch-here [set plabel ticks]
end
```

This is how it works:

[image]

Random patches are colored Red to show walls or obstacles, one turtle is created in a random location with a random target which is colored green:

I have used a variable to store all available patches which turtle can step on , but since I have considered a target for the turtle, turtle chooses the one patch which is closest to the target, and since I have noticed in some cases it might go in circle I have asked the turtle to leave tick number which is its move number as a plabel, you can use a variable for that for specifying if that path was already selected or not.

[image]